# ui:scrollerWrapper scrollTo method help

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, scrolling

I'm building a Lightning Component that includes a `ui:scrollerWrapper`, containing an `aura:iteration` of varying length. I want the scroller to default `scrollTo` the bottom.

I found the `ui:scrollerWrapper` documentation where they mention a `scrollTo` method, but I can't seem to get it to work.

My markup:

```
<ui:scrollerWrapper aura:id="scroller" class="scrollerSize" >
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.Messages}" var="Message">
        <c:MessageTile Message="{!Message}" />
    </aura:iteration>
</ui:scrollerWrapper>
```

My css:

```
.THIS.scrollerSize {
     height: 400px;
  }
```

My controller handler:

```
updateScroll : function(component, event, helper){
    var scroller = component.find("scroller");
    scroller.scrollTo("bottom");
}
```

It finds the scroller component -- I did a `console.log(scroller)` in my handler and it returns:

```
 markup://ui:scrollerWrapper {17:0} {scroller}{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }
```

It doesn't throw an error on the `scroller.scrollTo("bottom")` line, but it doesn't scroll.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the element large enough to scroll? Make sure that there's enough height for it to make a difference.

Comment: Yes, at least 2x context for available height.

Comment: I meant... *content*

Comment: I figured out the issue: I was calling the updateScroll function BEFORE the scroller was rendered. It works when I call it from afterRender.

Comment: ah. Makes sense. Perhaps add an answer for that? It could help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue: I was calling the updateScroll function BEFORE the scroller was rendered. It works when I call it from afterRender.

Comment: Can you please accept this answer so it no longer shows up as an open question?